# Send notification from TFS after code generation and validation from Sparx EA

Tags: c#, tfs, enterprise-architect

We are generating our source code from **Enterprise Architect (v13) diagrams**. The models and the source code is under version control in TFS and we are using TFS for build automation. The problem is that sometimes the developers aren't generating new source files after checking in a new model so the code and the model are inconsistent.

My question:

Is it possible to automatically generate the code from the model on
TFS then compare it to the latest code base, and if there is a
difference send some form of notification? Or is there some better way
to notify the developers about this inconsistency?

Comment: If the code and the model are inconsistent, is the build will fail?

Answer (score 0):

TFS can't achieve your requirement by default. But if the build will fail or have warnings when code and the model are inconsistent, it's suggested use [gated check-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers#gated). Otherwise, you'll need to code a solution to listen to check-in event.

Answer (score 0):

From the Enterprise Architect side you can definitely write an add-in or even a script that might help.
Unfortunately there is not really an event for the check-in of a package that you can hook onto with an add-in.

A possible option is to restrict access to the standard check-in feature using security and provide the check-in functionality through a script or add-in, using the API of EA.

You code could then not only do the check-in, but also generate the code, and compare it to the existing code in TFS.

I'm pretty sure you could also tackle this by writing some kind of automation from the TFS side, but I don't have any experience in that field